# How to handle large number of messages for MS teams Notification Bots with considering rate limit that is present?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, rate-limiting

Idea is to send notifications to users with direct messages. Because of that notification only bot need to be implemented. Reading documentation of MS Teams leads to information that we have 15000 across all threads in a data center (across multiple tenants).

Didn't find what are consequences when you hit this limits too often. Of course throttling mechanism need to exists, but with this limits I am not sure how to handle a large number of notifications I need to send from one bot across multiple clients(to be considered one bot per client if that is allowed to avoid this limit per data center for all).

Or any other idea how to handle notifications from one producer through bot to multiple consumers of those notifications on different addresses?

Is there any different pricing plan if you want to extend limits?

Comment: Can you share a link where you saw 15000 as the limit?

Comment: Here you can check "Bot per data center limit" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit

Comment: thanks I've been meaning to look into that

Comment: @NikolaPuzovic - do you have a bot that's hitting these limits now? If so, can you give us the bot ID? We can take a look.

Comment: The app template here implements a throttling strategy for a similar scenario - https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-company-communicator-app

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Still researching our options before we make a decision to implement one. This limiting is now the biggest concern since we have a lot of users (few millions) and a lot of events we want to cover in later versions. Also if we reach those limits what happens then? Extra charging or bot is suspended.

Comment: @AndrewClear Thanks, I will take a look on this solution. Just wanted to check first preconditions that exists. If we have a lot of messages throttling strategy is not enough, since some messages will be delivered with a big delay. It is a good not to hit 429 too often for sure, but just need to check business point of view also.